# Unable to enter text in text box in frame included in a frame with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I cannot enter text in a text box of a frame which is in an other frame.
Here is my environment : IE 10, latest Selenium driver 2.40.0, tests are developped in Java, I am using a file properties that contains all the Xpaths of my elements.
Here is my code, I tried in two different ways to edit my text box but both didn't work.

```
WebElement firstFrame = getDriverProvider().get().findElement(getLocator(frame));
String firstFrameLink = firstFrame.getAttribute("src");
getDriverProvider().get().switchTo().frame(firstFrame);
//getDriverProvider().get().switchTo().activeElement();
WebElement secondFrame = getDriverProvider().get().findElement(getLocator(field));
String secondFrameLink = secondFrame.getAttribute("src");
getDriverProvider().get().switchTo().frame(secondFrame);
WebElement element = getDriverProvider().get().findElement(getLocator("Input.field"));
//getDriverProvider().get().switchTo().activeElement();
JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor)getDriverProvider().get();
jsx.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
jsx.executeScript("arguments[0].value='testdata';", element);
String s = (String) jsx.executeScript("return arguments[0].getAttribute('name')", element);
//System.out.println(s);
element.click();
element.sendKeys("toto");
```

I am sure that my switches to frame is working because I managed to get attribute of an element of the second frame (String s in my code) I have tried all what I have found on internet

```
1. switchTo().activeElement()
```

=> Doesn't solve my issue

```
2. Use javascript to enter text jsx.executeScript("arguments[0].value='testdata';",  element)
```

=> Doesn't work even if I have no error, the text is not written in the textbox

```
3. Selenium method element.click()
```

=> Doesn't work gives me org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element

```
4. Selenium method element.sendKeys("toto")
```

=> Doesn't work gives me org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not displayed

Comment: Can you post the html as well?

Comment: I am sorry I cannot, I have this issue at work so I cannot post html...

Comment: @user3414662: Then there is not much we can help you with.

Comment: No I am not using WYSIWYG editors, I will try to filter my html in order to be able to post it

Comment: May be it come from the attribute onblur="updateCardHolder()"?